Proving that $ \{0^i10^i\mid i\geqslant 1\}$ is non-regular, using only closure results and the fact that $\{a^nb^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$ is non-regular
I've been thinking about this problem for several hours, but I couldn't complete the proof.
here is what I did:
suppose $L'$ is regular ($L' = \{0^i 1 2^i\mid i \geqslant 0\}$). we define the homomorphism function as below:
$$h:\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
\{0,1,2\}& \to & \{0,1\}\\
x & \mapsto& \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0 & \text{if }x=0\\
01 & \text{if }x=1\\
1& \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.
\end{array}$$
then we got $h(L') = \{0^n 1^n \mid n \geqslant 1\}$. by contradiction, $L'$ is non-regular.
I don't know how to prove that $L = \{0^i 1 0^i\mid i\geqslant 1\}$ is non-regular using the fact that $L'$ is non-regular. please help me

yes sir. after an intersection I proved it. but it was tricky
